# Android Studio HTTPS and SSL Certificate

Tags: java, php, android-studio, ssl, ssl-certificate

currently, i'm in the midst of developing mobile apps for Android using Android Studio.

so far, login/senddata/getdata/viewdata in my mobile apps work like a charm in my local PC and **HTTP web**. i use ***HttpUrlConnection*** in my coding

the problem is how to make my mobile apps run/send data/retrieve data/communicate with PHPMySQL in my **HTTPS** server.

its only working on HTTP web server. 
HTTPS does not work at all and my mobile apps is crashed and stop working.

i have test my mobile apps into both **HTTP & HTTPS server (SSL & Self-signed certificate)**

is there any addition on the coding that i need to be aware of to make it accessible into HTTPS ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The official Android documentation for HTTPS](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) has details about how HTTPS connections work in Android, including commonly seen errors.

If you have a trusted certificate that was issued by a CA or a reseller, your current code with HttpURLConnection should work fine. From https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html,

> Calling `openConnection()` on a URL with the "https" scheme will return an `HttpsURLConnection`, which allows for overriding the default `HostnameVerifier` and `SSLSocketFactory`. An application-supplied `SSLSocketFactory` created from an `SSLContext` can provide a custom `X509TrustManager` for verifying certificate chains and a custom `X509KeyManager` for supplying client certificates.

If you're using self signed certificates (not recommended in Production), [this article at CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826045/Android-security-Implementation-of-Self-signed-SSL) describes the process to handle this.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) . my https server (https://eapps.puncakniaga.com.my) . it says the connection is not private. it has certificate but not valid . is that cause the problem ?

Comment: here's my login code in android studio. http://www.puncakniaga.com.my/pnhbnew2/Login.txt , http://www.puncakniaga.com.my/pnhbnew2/LoginTask.txt

Comment: Probably. The site uses a self signed certificate. If you're planning on obtaining a valid certificate from an SSL certificate vendor, do that and deploy it on to the server rather than try and build escape routes for self signed certificates in your app. Also,  you seem to be using outdated versions of Apache HTTP Server (2.2.3 from 2006) and OpenSSL (0.9.8d from 2006). Update these unless you want to be vulnerable to a ton of SSL flaws and attacks. You can check the security of your SSL configuration at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eapps.puncakniaga.com.my&ignoreMismatch=on

Comment: yeah . in the midst of upgrading but i use another server . if the SSL is valid , does it solve the problem on my coding links above or i need major change ?

Comment: Code looks OK to me and should work with a valid certificate. But then again, I'm a human. Test it once the certificate is deployed and post any errors you see.

Answer (score -1):

With auto-certificates you will not work 
Try for free ssl 7 days https://www.globessl.com/

Comment: thanks for the reply :) . i already have https server . just want to know how to make it accessible for my mobile apps since my mobile apps need to get/send the data into that server https. cheers